# How to call showOpenDialog() from Angular?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, electron

I'm trying to develop a very simple app using the latest versions of Angular and Electron. For this, I followed the tutorials of Angular and Electron. After a whole day of trial and error, finally I can start my application ([source code on GitHub](https://github.com/mu88/FotoManager/tree/develop)).
Now I'm struggling with such a basic thing like opening a dialog. I've tried to follow the [Electron documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog) and adapt it as far as I understand, but when executing the following code, Angular stops working:

```
// file: \src\app\app.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { remote } from 'electron';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'FotoManager';

  openImages(){
    console.log("function called");
    var {dialog} = remote;
    dialog.showOpenDialog({properties: ['openFile', 'openDirectory', 'multiSelections']});
  }
}
```

The file `\src\app\app.component.html` looks like this:

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    {{ title }}
  </h1>
</div>

<button (click)="openImages()">Open images</button>
```

When removing the last two lines of `openImages()`, everything works properly (Angular is working, I see the button and clicking the button results in logging `function called` in the console).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, the first problem I do spot is this: var {dialog} = remote; Why are you putting dialog inside brackets? This seems wrong to me. What happens if you do it this way:  "var dialog = remote;"?

Comment: Then Visual Studio Code complains in the last line that `showOpenDialog` is not a member of `remote`.

Comment: Thats because you cannot access `showOpenDialog` on the `remote` export object. `var dialog = remote.dialog` will give you a dialog object upon which you can use `showOpenDialog`.

Comment: Thx! Now I can start the app, but Angular is not working, When opening Electron's developer tools, I see the error `fs.existsSync is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a lot of time, I finally found [this hack](http://electron.rocks/angular2-electron/). Now I have the following code which works for me:
File `index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Fotomanager</title>
  <base href="./">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <script>  
    var electron = require('electron');  
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

And `my.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

declare var electron: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'FotoManager';

  openImages(){
    console.log("function called");
    electron.remote.dialog.showOpenDialog({properties: ['openFile', 'openDirectory', 'multiSelections']});
  }
}
```